# unable to load a webpage in android web view

Tags: android, android-webview

I've created a simple android application which loads a webpage using android WebView. But unfortunately the content isn't displaying for the following url:

```
https://portal.e-idara.com
```

[image]

Also I'm getting the following logcats:

```
07-27 13:25:23.021 11972-11972/com.eidara E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(89)] stat /data/user/0/com.eidara/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
07-27 13:25:23.021 11972-11972/com.eidara E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.eidara/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
07-27 13:25:23.191 11972-11972/com.eidara D/ConnectivityManager: requestNetwork; getAppId(CallingUid) : 10141, CallingPid : 11972
07-27 13:25:23.311 11972-11972/com.eidara D/NETWORK_STATE: AVAIALBLE
07-27 13:25:23.386 11972-12059/com.eidara E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

I've changed the url to `http://google.com` and `https://facebook.com` and it works fine.

Following is the code snippet for this application. Can anyone please guide me what I'm missing and why the content isn't showing.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.eidara;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.eidara.constants.EidaraWebConstants;
import com.eidara.utils.EidaraWebClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Log.d("NETWORK_STATE","AVAIALBLE");
            Log.d("DIRECTORY_LOCATION",Environment.getExternalStorageState());

            webView = findViewById(R.id.eidara_main_webview);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new EidaraWebClient());
//            webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.url));
            webView.loadUrl("https://portal.e-idara.com");
        }
        else
            {
                Log.d("NETWORK_STATE","UNAVAIALBLE");
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

    }
}
```

**EidaraWebClient**

```
public class EidaraWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(EidaraWebConstants.URL);
        //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/eidara_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eidara">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you get any error on the console?Is it a CORS error?

Comment: I am also getting same error. Any solution for it.

Comment: @MaulikSantoki not yet, If you resolved this then please share the resolution

Comment: Same error here too

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue where I was trying to go to a site and just had regular HTTP site.  Nothing fancy and I got the same chromium error.  Solved it by adding two lines before the load.

```
    webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webview.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```